# Implement Locust test from existing Python script

Tags: python, locust

I have a working python script like this using company developed code as packages below (mycompany):

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz
from mycompany.ssa.environment import VENDOR_DEV, VENDOR_TEST, VENDOR_PROD, VENDOR_PREPROD
from mycompany.ssa.environment import BradyEnvironment
from mycompany.ssa.timeseries import Calendar, MetaInfo, Resolution, TimeSpan, 
TransformMethod, TsIdentity, UtcTime
from mycompany.ssa.wrappers import ReadWrapper, _Utils

rw = ReadWrapper()
dict_vendor_env = {'VENDOR_PROD': VENDOR_PROD, 'VENDOR_PREPROD': VENDOR_PREPROD}

# Monthly resolution om time series
ts_ids = [367902, 367875]
start = '2022-11-01'
end = '2022-12-01'
time_zone = 'Etc/GMT-1'
start_time = dt.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_time = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')

# Define wrapper
rw = ReadWrapper()

# Set resolution
resolution = Resolution.HOUR

# Set Python timezone
time_zone = pytz.timezone(time_zone)

# Set transformation method
transform_method = TransformMethod.DEFAULT

#Set Vendor environment
vendor_env = dict_vendor_env['VENDOR_PROD']

df = rw.read_transformed_by_dates(ts_ids, start_time, end_time, transform_method,  resolution, 
read_from=vendor_env, tz=time_zone, max_time_series_per_query=7500) 
df
```

I want to call the line

```
df = rw.read_transformed_by_dates
```

once per virtual user in Locust. Task?

How do I surround this script with Locust code to make it runnable?

Just decorate/define the line with read_transformed_by_dates as a task?

A working example would be appreciated.